# perl: chdir in perl and call chdir from system

Tags: perl, chdir, qx

In my perl script, use `chdir` command from Perl iteself works well as following: 
`chdir $fold_path`

but use `qx` call `chdir` command of linux doesn't work as following:

`qx(chdir $fold_path)`

so what is the reason? Not so clear!

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons:

1. There's no `chdir` in Linux. It's called `cd`.
2. After you change directory in `qx`, it only affects the child process. It doesn't change the working directory for the parent, i.e. the Perl script that called it.

Comment: There *is* a `chdir` in Windows, though.

Comment: @JimDavis: But the question mentions "`chdir` command of linux".